# Value type of the class complex, or class itself

Tags: c++, templates, c++11, types, template-meta-programming

I'm trying to have a class similar to the following

```
#include <cstdlib>
#include <iostream>
#include <typeinfo>
#include <type_traits>
#include <complex>

template<class K, class T = typename std::conditional<std::is_class<K>::value, typename K::value_type, K>::type>
class A {
    public:
        K v;
        T u;
        void type() {
            std::cout << typeid(u).name() << std::endl;
        }
};

int main() {
    A<std::complex<double>> a;
    a.type();
    A<std::complex<float>> b;
    b.type();
    A<float> c;
    c.type();
    A<double> d;
    d.type();
    return 0;
}
```

Such that the ouput will be:

```
d
f
f
d
```

Stated otherwise, I need the variable `u` to be of type `T` if `K` is of type `std::complex<K>`, or `K` otherwise. Can this be achieved with C++11 ? Thanks.

Comment: Why not using template specialization ?

Comment: Which problem are you encountering?

Comment: In my full project, there are many classes inheriting from `A`, and many other members. So I think that explicit specialization will require a lot of copy/pasting. @KerrekSB, my code doesn't compile, because for `A<float>` and `A<double>`, there is no such thing as `K::value_type`.

Comment: Why do you need any data members? You can just say `typeid(T)`.

Comment: @BigDawg: Yes, thanks, now I get it. The general answer for switching on class template parameter traits is partial specialization, and for switching on function template parameter traits it is SFINAE.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use partial specialization to get the right type, maybe like this:

```
template <typename T, bool> struct ValueType
{
    using type = T;
};
template <typename T> struct ValueType<T, true>
{
    using type = typename T::value_type;
};

template <class K>
struct A 
{
    using T = typename ValueType<K, std::is_class<K>::value>::type;

    void type()
    {
        std::cout << typeid(T).name() << std::endl;
    }
};
```

If you want an appropriate data member, you can make the type alias a class member, too, and then declare a data member of type `T`.

Comment: I have the exact same compilation error as before, e.g. `error: type 'float' cannot be used prior to '::' because it has no members`.

Comment: Aaannnddd now I realize my question was just plain stupid. Thank you.

Comment: @BigDawg: I don't know. Just by itself there's nothing wrong with the question. Maybe your motivation is stupid, but you don't have to tell anyone :-)

Answer (score 3):

You can easily use partial template specialisation and a trait for this:

```
template <class T>
struct TypeForU_Class
{
  typedef T type;
};

template <class T>
struct TypeForU_Class<std::complex<T>>
{
  typedef T type;
};

template <class T>
using TypeForU = typename TypeForU_Class<T>::type;


template <class K, class T>
class A
{
public:
  K v;
  TypeForU<T> u;
  // rest as before
};
```